# SQL Profiler shows over 5000 Queries running on Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, database, performance

I am having a site on Magento 1.9.2 . Past few days i am seeing some issues on the backend. The First Byte of the Site takes too long. After hours of R&D I came to know that there are over 5000 queries running at one time. 
The Website is hosted on AWS EC2(It was on t2.micro but while debugging we have increased it to c4.large) and We are using RDS for DB. 
I have tried repairing the database with the [Database Repair Tool](http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/magento/database-repair-tool.html)
and it showed me some issues like missing Auto Increments from tables.

```
Error #1062: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY' on SQL: ALTER TABLE `eav_entity_attribute` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`entity_attribute_id`)
Error #1062: Duplicate entry '140' for key 'IDX_PERSISTENT_SESSION_CUSTOMER_ID' on SQL: ALTER TABLE `persistent_session` ADD UNIQUE `IDX_PERSISTENT_SESSION_CUSTOMER_ID` (`customer_id`)
Repair Log
Add missing index(es) "UNQ_INDEX_EVENT_TYPE_ENTITY_ENTITY_PK" to table "index_event"
Add missing index(es) "UNQ_REPORT_VIEWED_PRODUCT_INDEX_VISITOR_ID_PRODUCT_ID, UNQ_REPORT_VIEWED_PRODUCT_INDEX_CUSTOMER_ID_PRODUCT_ID, IDX_REPORT_VIEWED_PRODUCT_INDEX_STORE_ID, IDX_REPORT_VIEWED_PRODUCT_INDEX_ADDED_AT, IDX_REPORT_VIEWED_PRODUCT_INDEX_PRODUCT_ID" to table "report_viewed_product_index"
Add missing index(es) "PRIMARY, IDX_REVIEW_ENTITY_ID, IDX_REVIEW_STATUS_ID, IDX_REVIEW_ENTITY_PK_VALUE" to table "review"
Add missing index(es) "IDX_REVIEW_DETAIL_REVIEW_ID, IDX_REVIEW_DETAIL_STORE_ID, IDX_REVIEW_DETAIL_CUSTOMER_ID" to table "review_detail"
Add missing foreign key(s) "FK_INDEX_PROCESS_EVENT_EVENT_ID_INDEX_EVENT_EVENT_ID, FK_INDEX_PROCESS_EVENT_PROCESS_ID_INDEX_PROCESS_PROCESS_ID" to table "index_process_event"
Add missing foreign key(s) "FK_RATING_OPTION_VOTE_REVIEW_ID_REVIEW_REVIEW_ID" to table "rating_option_vote"
Add missing foreign key(s) "FK_REVIEW_DETAIL_REVIEW_ID_REVIEW_REVIEW_ID, FK_REVIEW_DETAIL_STORE_ID_CORE_STORE_STORE_ID" to table "review_detail"
Add missing foreign key(s) "FK_REVIEW_STORE_REVIEW_ID_REVIEW_REVIEW_ID, FK_REVIEW_STORE_STORE_ID_CORE_STORE_STORE_ID" to table "review_store"
```

I used AOEScheduler to disable the cron for temporary basis. But it doesnt work
Can anyone suggest how do I go forward on this ? I don't have much traffic right now as the site is still in development.It is loading too slow. 
While using Neor Sql Profiler I saw, There is a huge load on Mysql. I just dont know from where is this coming from ..
Thanks

[image]

Comment: It's possible that bots are crawling your site, they are violent sometimes, check for access logs on your Apache / Nginx.

Comment: Change your database user access and wait for few minutes. Then update local.xml with new credentials and check once.

Comment: @Tonmoy I changed the password for the user which was used in local.xml. It increased to 8000 but then decreased to 1000. What does this mean.. Note that it hasnt stopped...

Comment: @JonathanRibas I have kept the site on No Index No Follow... Plus i am trying to find the logs..

Comment: https://ibb.co/fVkrqa
https://ibb.co/c1dY3v

Comment: remove each an every cron from your server and see what happen!

Comment: I have disabled each one of them from the backend. @Tonmoy

Comment: not backend...from server dude. @user9090

Comment: I have checked from server. there are no crons running :(